# Automated Email Source Verification Test

Tags: email, selenium, testing, automation, html-email

I want to improve our QA process for data driven email projects. 
As you may know, one-to-one communication content fragments are often unique so we need to assure that certain modules and variables are placed correctly (or even at all) within the assembled and ready to send templates. Additionally we could check for coding standards. This can be done manually but I would prefer automation here.

Because personal data is inserted at send time, I think the best approach for inspection would be fetching emails from test mailbox and process them afterwards with a (local) test system.

Is anyone familiar with automated tests in this field? Maybe a system based on Selenium or a similar approach?

Please note: I do not want to address any deliverability issues here.

Any thoughts or comments are welcome!

Thanks in advance, 
Daniel

Comment: You probably should rephrase your question to be a little more focused. What do you actually want to know... how to do it or are you just polling if there's anyone that is familiar with this stuff? Are you automating Outlook client or gmail or ??? What do you need to validate?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. OK, I try to rephrase a bit. What I'm looking for has nothing to do with any specific email client software, I don't want to check, whether emails render correctly or in any specific way. I want to check for code correctness and the availability of certain properties or attributes within the code that forms the email (layout). Better?

Comment: Maybe?... I would suggest that you edit your actual question and put that info in there so that others will be more likely to see it. It sounds like this is something that should be done with dev unit tests in the code that generates the email. Maybe if you give an example of something you want to check it will make what you are looking for more evident.